# KeyPress doesn't wokr for password EditText types

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

Why this code doesn't work on Xamarin.Android? It sould change the `enable` propertie for the botton if the field of the password is typed.

```
        EditText edit_user_001 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_user_001);
        EditText edit_password_001 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.id_edit_password_001);
        Button btn_login_001 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.id_btn_login_001);

        edit_password_001.KeyPress += (sender, e) => {
            if (edit_user_001.Text.ToString().Equals("") | edit_password_001.Text.ToString().Equals("")){
                btn_login_001.Enabled = false;
            } else {
                btn_login_001.Enabled = true;
            }
        };
```

This is the .xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_user_001"
        android:text="@string/txt_user_001"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_edit_user_001"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/txt_password_001"
        android:id="@+id/id_txt_password_001"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_edit_password_001"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

`android:inputType="textPassword` creates conflict. If I changes for `android:inputType="text` it works fine. Is there and alternative or a solution?

Comment: "creates conflict" - what does this mean, exactly?  Are you getting an error or exception?  What specifically is the problem?

Comment: It is a bug. I can't type text into the input using my keyboard (in the Emulator). Also if I use the virtual keyboard of the Emulator,`edit_password_001.Text.ToString().Equals("")` is always `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android:inputType="textPassword creates conflict. If I changes for android:inputType="text it works fine. Is there and alternative or a solution?

Yes, I encounter same problem for KeyPress when setting EditText  `android:inputType="textPassword"`.
You can use `TextChanged` method to achieve the same effects.

```
 private void Password_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (username.Text.Equals("") || password.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```